# Ethers.js && Angular:

Tags: angular, ethereum, web3js

I am trying to connect ethers.js (last version) with Angular (last version) but I cannot find the right documentation or an "Hello world" example. 
Does it mean that I can use ethers.js only on the server side ?

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: what did you try until now? did you try to install by npm and import into your module and your controller?

Comment: npm install ethers --save
import { ??? } from 'ethers';

what should i import ? what should I inject ....i am looking for an example

Comment: you can import all library and use all methods you need. it's enough to import in this way. import * as anyNameEthers from 'ethers'

then in your controller you can access to all methods by writing anyNameEthers.methodYouWant()

Comment: thank you.  i will try then :-)

Comment: did you try it ?

Comment: no, it doesn't i have a problem on this line import { anyNameEthers  } from ethers;
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(3,23): error TS1141: String literal expected.

Comment: you didn't understand well I said to import in this way: import * as anyNameEthers from 'ethers'; you can replace "anyNameEthers" with any name name you want. NOT import as you wrote mport { anyNameEthers } from ethers;

Comment: I did it it works thank you !